# Getting timestampdiff not working in Grails Gorm

Tags: mysql, sql, grails, grails-orm

I want to get time difference between two dates saved in MySql DB inside Grails criteria. For this purpose I have added below code in domain's mapping section.

```
formula: "(SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_record, end_record))"
```

But `SECOND` is being treated as field and throwing sql syntax error.
There must be some trick to fix it, expecting it from SO community. Thanks

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'this_.SECOND, this_.start_record, this_.end_record))) as y6_ from answer_meta_da' at line 1.
```

> Grails Version: 3.3.9 | JVM Version: 1.8.0_121

Comment: "But SECOND is being treated as field and throwing sql syntax error." - What is the syntax error?

Comment: Does `formula: "TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_record, end_record)"` work?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Added error. No `formula: "TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_record, end_record)"` has no effect.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the domain class?

Comment: Similar to this:
`class AnswerMetaData {
 Date startRecord
 Date endRecord

 Long timeTaken
 static mapping = {
  timeTaken formula: "(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_record, end_record))"
 }
}`

Comment: If you would like to file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues, we can take a look.  Thanks for the feedback.